# Trying to figure out why the split method is not printg out right

Tags: java

The words printed out after the split command are not printing out in ascending order.  I do not think I have it placed in the right spot of the code, but i am unsure exactly were to place it.  It prints out the whole text passage word for word without any punctuation marks as desired, but it wont print in ascending (alphabetical) order.  Any help would be great.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws 
        FileNotFoundException, IOException 
{
    Scanner ci = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a text file to open: ");
    String filename = ci.next();
    System.out.println("");

    File file = new File(filename);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String str;

    while((str = br.readLine())!= null)
    {
        String sp[] = str.split("[\\s\\.,;:\\?!]+");
        for (String sr : sp )
        {
            System.out.println(sr);
        }            

        sb.append(str);
        sb.append(" ");
        // System.out.println(str);            
    }

    ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sb.toString().toLowerCase());
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) 
    {
        String s = st.nextToken();
        text.add(s);
    }

    System.out.println("\n" + "Words Printed out in Ascending "
                            + "(alphabetical) order: " + "\n");

    List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(text);
    Collections.sort(arrayList);
    for (Object ob : arrayList)
    {
        System.out.println("\t" + ob.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the array ever gets sorted?

Comment: You seem to first split the string on all punctuation, then glue it back together and then split it again... Any reason for gluing the array back again?

Comment: The array does get sorted...and I do not really know why I'm doing that, I don't have much experience with split

Comment: have u actually debugged it and checked?

Comment: yes i have checked it

Comment: what is the input file content?

Comment: The input file is just a text file that has a paragraph of words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing the words twice, once after you've splitted the text on punctuation, then again after you've glued it back together, splitted it again and finally sorted it.

However, in the line-reading `while` you're splitting each line, but you're then ignoring the result of that split (besides printing it) and you continue to add the original line to `sb`.

You probably want to turn `sb` into an `ArrayList`, then add each word (`sr` from `sp` in your `for(sr : sp)` loop) to `sb` and sort that.

You can then remove the whole part with `StringTokenizer` and sort the `ArrayList` immediately. Like this:

```
ArrayList<String> sb = new ArrayList<String>();
String str;

while((str = br.readLine())!= null)
{
    String sp[] = str.split("[^\\w]+");
    for (String sr : sp )
    {
        sb.add(sr);
        // System.out.println(sr);
    }          
}
sb = Collections.sort(sb);
```

Comment: ok so it know splits and sorts properly (thanks!!!), but it puts any word that began with a capitol (uppercase) letter first.  Any idea how to stop that

Comment: That's because capitals come first in the (ASCII-)alphabet, you could convert the words to lower-case when inserting them into `sb`. (Your old code does that when initialising the `StringTokenizer`).